# Is there anyway to retrieve the properties of an individual TiledTile?

Tags: monogame, monogame-extended

I managed to get a list of all the tiles in a layer of a tmx map by iterating through the `IReadOnlyList<TiledTile> Tiles` in `TiledTileLayer` and enumerating the values into another list. But I need to be able to iterate through that list and check for a certain property. However, `TiledTile` has no `properties` variable and no `getProperties()` method. How would I do this?

Comment: First link I got when looking for "monogame tiledtile" was this : http://community.monogame.net/t/tiledtile-properties/7581/4

Comment: The link you provided goes over using an object layer. Object layers are different than regular layers.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the properties you're after exist on the [Tileset Tile](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/blob/develop/Source/MonoGame.Extended.Tiled/TiledMapTilesetTile.cs).

There's been a lot of work going into the Tiled feature of MonoGame.Extended lately. Even since you asked this question a lot of things have changed. If there's something missing, raising a [github issue](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/issues) is a good way to get some eyeballs on it.

Sorry if I've missed something. I checked the Tiled editor to see what properties you might be talking about and I'm not sure how you'd go about setting Properties at the tile level.